# Splitting a large CSV file and converting into multiple Parquet files - Safe?

Tags: python, csv, parquet

I learnt, the **parquet file format** stores a bunch of metadata and uses various compressions to store data in an efficient way, when it comes to size and query-speed.

And it possibly generates multiple files out of, let's say: one input, like from a Panda dataframe.

Now, I have a **large CSV** file and I want to **convert it into a parquet** file format. Naively, I would remove the header (store elsewhere for later) and chunk the file up in blocks with n lines. Then turn each chunk into parquet (here Python):

```
table = pyarrow.csv.read_csv(fileName)
pyarrow.parquet.write_table(table, fileName.replace('csv', 'parquet'))
```

I guess the method doesn't much matter. From what I see, at least with a small **test data set and no extra context**, I get one parquet file per csv file **(1:1)**.

For now that is all I need, **as I am not doing queries** on "the whole", logical data set. I use the raw files, as input to a further cleaning step that is nifty to do with the csv format. And I haven't yet tried reading the files...

**Do I have to readd the header to each CSV chunk at the least?**

Is this as straight-forward as I think, or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried? pd.read_parquet works very intuitively. You shouldn’t need to remove the header or partition manually (if the header is the column names, just leave them there - parquet stores column names).

Comment: Yes, question is, do I have to repeat the header in all chunks or leave it away completely? As there is not 1 but N files...

Comment: @raoulsson why would you get Mutiple parquet files? The way you are doing it, you will always get one parquet file.

Comment: In case you want to split the csv to Mutiple parquet file then you will have to include the headers as well. Headers can't be left out.

Comment: @shetty15 I need to split it, yes, that's the point. Why not put your comment into an answer and I will accept it? Thx

Comment: But why not just use multiple row groups on parquet? Parquet provides a means of efficiently giving access to specific columns or blocks of rows on read. There should be no need to split the file into multiple batches manually at all

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I would agree, but the file could be too big and I would like to process it in parallel, if that is doable. That's what I need to know, if that is a navie idea, as parquet might bring more to the table than I expected... (plus my clients needs this to be answered in general)

Comment: Writing it to a single file with multiple row groups will work. However, the application that's later reading this file should support features like row group pruning. How are you planning to read/process these files once they are created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a parquet dataset with Mutiple files, All the files should have matching schema. In your case, when you split the csv file into Mutiple parquet files, you will have to include the csv headers in each chunk to create a valid parquet file.

Note that parquet is a compressed format (with a high compression ratio). Parquet data will be much smaller than the csv data. On top of that, applications that read parquet file usually prefer fewer large parquet file and not many small parquet files.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to write a partitioned parquet file is with [`dask.dataframe`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe.html). You could even read in the data with [`dask.dataframe.read_csv`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.read_csv.html) and then you don't have to do any conversion:

```py
import dask.dataframe

# here, the block size will determine the partition boundaries, which will
# be preserved in the parquet file. So if you have a 5 GB file, this would
# write 50 partitions:
df = dask.dataframe.read_csv(fileName, blocksize="100MB")
df.to_parquet(fileName.replace(".csv", ".parquet"))
```

Comment: thanks, both great, gave the "accepted" to the shetty15 as he was first. But great addition, maybe that is practially the best way. No overengineering on my side...

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work with compressed files: `UserWarning: Warning gzip compression does not support breaking apart files
Please ensure that each individual file can fit in memory and
use the keyword blocksize=None to remove this message`